# how comes this horrible world to exist?

Tags: grammar, idioms, vocabulary

In the quote below, what does the first line mean?

> "How comes this horrible world to exist?"
>   Catice did not answer.
>   "Who is Surtur?"

source: *A Voyage to Arcturus*

What I understand is: *How come such a terrible world exists?* But I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, I agree, strange way to put it.

Comment: Did you copy it correctly?  Is this from a non-native speaker?  It's not grammatical as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's probably "mock archaic" rather than a faithful reflection of a once-common usage, but your paraphrasing is correct, if colloquial. More "standard" phrasing might be, for example, *How does this terrible world come to exist?*, or *How does it come about that this terrible world exists?* @Jim: it's perfectly grammatical - just an unusual dated/formal/poetic word order.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- Ok, yes, agree.  somehow my eye missed the 's' on *comes*.  I see it now.

Comment: @Jim It's 1920's science fiction, written by a Scotsman: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Voyage_to_Arcturus Used to be quite popular in university SF courses.

Comment: This is perfectly normal Early Modern English - anyone who has read a book more than a century old can tell you that. It simply means *how has this horrible world come to exist?*

Comment: @Anonym I agree, you should post that as an answer if you can find something to quote to back it up.

Comment: Early Modern English ‘What thinke you of this English, tel me I pray you.’ - Not 'What do you think of this English...' [John Florio, Florio his firste fruites (1578), ch. 27.](http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-time/early-modern-english-an-overview/)

Answer (score 1):

I would render it as “How does such a horrible world come into existence?” The inflected third-person-singular form of *come* would seem to preclude reading it with *how* as a form of the idiom *how come* meaning *why,* not that the difference in meaning is enormous.

Lurking in the background here may be the fallacious “Optimist” doctrine that the world we live in must be “the best of all possible worlds” simply because it exists. As the title character of Voltaire’s *Candide* (a satire on this doctrine) wonders, after suffering a grotesque series of horrors, “If this is the best possible world, what must the others be like?”

Comment: Thank you so much for all the answers. The book was written in 1920s, so the archaic usage makes sense.